# Delete row from table and sqlite database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

I have some problem deleting rows from a database and table.

The problem is: I can swipe the row, tap the "delete" button, but nothing happens.

Probably i'm doing it wrong.

Can Somebody give me a tip?
Here there is all the program if you want to take a look:(updated)

http://cl.ly/9q7U

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [shoppingListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *keyValue = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"key"];

    [_tableView beginUpdates];
    [_tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //Here i got the SIGABRT error
    [_tableView endUpdates];

    sqlite3 *db;
    int dbrc; //Codice di ritorno del database (database return code)
    DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    const char *dbFilePathUTF8 = [appDelegate.dbFilePath UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_open(dbFilePathUTF8, &db);
    if (dbrc) {
        NSLog(@"Impossibile aprire il Database!");
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *dbps; //Istruzione di preparazione del database

    NSString *deleteStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"shoppinglist\" WHERE key='%@'", keyValue];

    const char *deleteStatement = [deleteStatementsNS UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);
    dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbps);


    //faccio pulizia rilasciando i database
    sqlite3_finalize(dbps);
    sqlite3_close(db);

}
}
```

#

Thanks to Akshay, finally i fixed this portion of code. I write here the solution for the ones who'll need it.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [shoppingListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *keyValue = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"key"];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    sqlite3 *db;
    int dbrc; //Codice di ritorno del database (database return code)
    DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DatabaseShoppingListAppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    const char *dbFilePathUTF8 = [appDelegate.dbFilePath UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_open(dbFilePathUTF8, &db);
    if (dbrc) {
        NSLog(@"Impossibile aprire il Database!");
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *dbps; //Istruzione di preparazione del database

    NSString *deleteStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"shoppinglist\" WHERE key='%@'", keyValue];

    const char *deleteStatement = [deleteStatementsNS UTF8String];
    dbrc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatement, -1, &dbps, NULL);
    dbrc = sqlite3_step(dbps);


    //faccio pulizia rilasciando i database
    sqlite3_finalize(dbps);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [shoppingListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView endUpdates];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

Comment: @Oiproks When asking a questions, please always tell us whether you have an error of some sorts, or you have an unexpected behavior and what the expected behavior is (which happens to be obvious in this case, but may not be obvious in general case).

Comment: Ok, sorry! I fixed the question.

Comment: @Oiproks Sorry for the interruption,my code is getting crashed at line   NSString *keyValue = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"key"];Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
        withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

inside `commitEditingStyle:` instead of `reloadData`. Also, make sure that you delete the entity from the DB & return one less from `numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: i tried as you said, but i receive SIGABRT on "[tableView endUpdates];", and I don't know how to return one less row... :( I'm not so skilled...

Comment: What do you return in numberOfRowsInSection: ? If you had 3 rows before swiping & were returning 3, now return 2.

Comment: There I return the number of items in the array shoppingListItems (return [shoppingListItems count];) charged from the db. How can I tell it to count one less?

Comment: Actually the program delete the content of the database. After i delete something, the simulator crash, i run it again, and the row is disappeared! So the problem is just in removing the row from the table!

Comment: The problem is the crash. You should delete the row from the DB between beginUpdates & endUpdates. If you are returning the right number after the swipe, you should be good.

Comment: it keeps crashing on "[tableView endUpdates];". How do I have to return the number of rows...

Comment: Your numberOfRowsInSection: will be called automatically, you just have to make sure that it returns the correct value. Most likely, you have not removed the item from your array shoppingListItems.

Comment: I did as you told me, i removed the item from the array with this `[shoppingListItems removeObjectsInArray:[shoppingListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];` or/and `[shoppingListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
` but now i have the same error (SIGABRT) in this line(s) of code... I'm really sorry i'm bothering you, but I'm going crazy... with this easy project. I have to give it to a teacher in few days and i can't see the end... Probably I'll pay someone to do it. Then I'll seriously study Objective-C.But now I have no time sadness

Comment: ok! I did it... thanks for your patience, you helped me a lot! I'll write the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line

```
NSString *insertStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"shoppinglist\" WHERE key=?", indexPath];
```

I think you want to have in `insertStatementsNS` this:

```
NSString *insertStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"shoppinglist\" WHERE key=%@", indexPath];
```

or

```
NSString *insertStatementsNS = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE FROM \"shoppinglist\" WHERE key='%@'", indexPath];
```

Comment: Well.. the problem is not only there! Actually i can't see if that one is working or not cos after I swipe and delete nothing happens... probably there is something wrong somewhere else :S

Comment: commitEditingStyle is calling ?

Comment: To read the correct value from the cell i did this.

`NSDictionary *rowVals = (NSDictionary *) [shoppingListItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *keyValue = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"key"];`

Then i pass the keyValue variable to the Query. I'm sure is more efficient.
But I still have problem deleting the row .____. that's so annoying!
If I link you the project, can you take a look? maybe is something stupid...

Comment: Something new! Actually the program delete the content of te database. After i delete something, the simulator crash, i run again, and the row is disappeared! So the problem is just in removing the row from the table!